# Visual Studio 2008 GUI controls changed language

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Today I had to open an old project to make some changes. I was surprised to see
that some form names, labels, and even strings inside the code has changed
from Arabic language into another weird text. I have to add that I did format
my laptop before opening the projects.

I had an old copy of the project but had the same issue too. Other projects that include Arabic text weren't affected.

Is there a way to solve this issue? Changing all the text back manually would take too much time.

Comment: You have an encoding issue.

Comment: is it windows related issue ?

Comment: It is [yet another Roslyn bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4264).  Always mention the VS version you use.

Comment: Version added . 2008

Comment: Issue solved . All what I had to do is change the windows language and location to Arabic/Lebanon . Your help is much appreciated